# HTML link to a CGI script

Tags: python-2.7

I am learning how to send data via CGI.I have a basic form with one field that I submit via CGI
    
    
    Name:

and below a python script that receive the field and show it

```
#!F:/Python/python.exe
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage() # instantiate only once!
name = form.getfirst('name', 'empty')

# Avoid script injection escaping the user input
name = cgi.escape(name)

print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>The submitted name was "%s"</p>
</body></html>
""" % name
```

My main problem is that the link between the two files does not work.Once I validate my form there is no execution of the python script,but a page with my code written inside.
On the otherhand if I past directly this url "http://localhost/cgi-bin/process_form.py?name=Joe",it works without any problem.
Do you have an idea about the origin of my error.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you told your webserver what to do with .py files ?

Comment: yes,and I have followed this tutorial               http://candordeveloper.com/2013/03/29/running-apache-on-windows-8-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver is configed that way to interpret python files inside cgi-bin. Check you webserver configuration and change it to desired directory.

Here are some links for Apache and Nginx:

1. http://wiki.nginx.org/SimplePythonFCGI
2. https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/129-servers/757148-configuring-apache2-to-run-python-scripts

Comment: yes I think it s configured to run Python files insides cgi-bin,because when I past http://localhost/cgi-bin/process_form.py?name=Joe in the browser I a page with my result.Am I wrong ??                                                                   Im using windows OS and I have followed this tutorial: http://candordeveloper.com/2013/03/29/running-apache-on-windows-8-with-python/